# Is it possible to auto-theme widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Google's mobile framework Flutter, you can build your app using either Cupterino (iOS) widgets or Material Design (Android) widgets. This means you have to build your app twice in order to create two different styles consistent to each device -- one time using Cupertino widgets to build for iOS, and then another time using Material Design widgets to build for Android. Is there a way to auto-theme these widgets to tailor to each platform so I can avoid building a Flutter app twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course this is possible. You can use the inherited [`Theme` widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme/of.html) to get the [`ThemeData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) object of your `MaterialApp`.

`ThemeData` has a [property called **`platform`**](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/platform.html), which can be used to supply different widgets for different platforms. In your *Android*-*iOS* case, it would look something like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext contect) => 
  Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? // ternary if statement to check for iOS
    CupertinoAlertDialog() : // Cupertino style dialog
    AlertDialog(); // Material style dialog
```

As you can see, you can use a [`TargetPlatform` constant](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/TargetPlatform-class.html) to check on what platform your application is running.

This can obviously also *be applied* to icons etc.

If you are using the *Flutter plugin* for Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, you can also use the *Flutter Inspector* to switch the `TargetPlatform` on the fly, i.e. *emulate* that the Flutter SDK is running on *iOS* even though you are on *Android* and **vise versa**.